# How can I reattach to my byobu/tmux session?

Tags: tmux, byobu

I'm using byobu with a tmux backend in Ubuntu 14.04. The standard methods for selecting/viewing sessions such as `byobu-select-session` and `tmux ls` do not find the session.

I created a session via incorrect syntax `byobu -S wiki` and later detached.  (I should have done `byobu new -s wiki`)

The session still exists, according to

```
$ ps aux | grep byobu
gert   4032  0.1  0.0  29988  8912 ?        Ss   Jun13   1:46 tmux -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc -S wiki
```

I can also see a reference to the session in `/tmp`

```
$ ls /tmp/tmux-1001/ -l
total 0
srwxrwx--- 1 gert gert 0 May 30 17:06 default=
srw-rw---- 1 gert gert 0 Jun 14 15:07 wiki=
```

Comment: Does `tmux ls` show this session?

Comment: I've not gotten myself into this situation since. I helped myself with an easier to remember (relative to frequency of use) alias of `alias byobunew='byobu new -s'`

Comment: I got myself into this situation again (different machine, no helpful alias), with no success recovering, though a difference is there's no separate file in /tmp/tmux-1001/.  Oh well, this was a minor session I'll just kill manually.

Comment: Note that starting byobu without any argument will usually open the last active session, although I'm not sure if it will work the way you want if you have multiple sessions running.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
byobu -S wiki ls
```

to see if the tmux session is still there. It probably is given your ps output, and will be listed as session 1. Then try

```
byobu -S wiki attach-session -t 1
```

Maybe specify the full path to where you can see the "wiki" unix socket that was created when you did `byobu -S wiki`, which will be in whatever directory you executed that command in originally. Other behavior may occur if byobu or tmux was customized, but basically after you specify `byobu -S <path-to-put-socket|path-to-existing-socket-including-socket-name>` everything following is going to get passed to tmux. tmux just needs byobu to tell it where to look for its sockets, otherwise it will look in TMPDIR or something by default.

Hope this helps. This is my first ever stackoverflow question that (1) wasn't already answered many different ways, and (2) I knew a possible answer or at least a pointer in the right direction. :)